# Do we say "the rope, the hair or the rubber band are broken or cut or split"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

This is a rubber band

[image]

And this is a rubber band that was cut

[image]

Also, look at the picture

[image]

Do we say "**The rubber band / rope is broken or cut or split**"? or do we have other specific terms to express it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Cut" means that someone used a knife or scissors on it. "Break" suggests that it isn't able to work properly. Split suggests to me that the rope is separated length wise.

> I cut the rope into 1 metre pieces and tied each length of cut rope to the corners of my tent.  (the rope was cut with a knife but it still "works")
>
> The rope broke as we tried to pull our car out of the mud, so we were completely stuck. The broken rope was too short to use. (the rope broke by accident and now doesn't work)
>
> Her hair had split ends, which she hated.

Comment: As James implies,  _cutting_ is deliberate,  _breaking_ is accidental.